# Moving data (based on a class) from .py to a dictonary in another .py file

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to store user input data in a dictonary in another python file. This is my first real python project and so if you have any suggestions about ways to simplify what i'm doing, please suggest. Thanks!

My Assignment class:

```
class Assignment(object):
def __init__(self, assignment_name, due_date):
    self.assignment_name = assignment_name
    self.due_date = due_date

def getassignment_name(self):
    return self.assignment_name

def getdue_date(self):
    return self.due_date

def __str__( xself):
    return "%s is due on %s" % (self.assignment_name, self.due_date)
```

My user input:

```
def questions():

    raw_input("Name Of Assignment?")

    raw_input("Due Date")




assignment_name = raw_input("Name Of Assignment?")

due_date = raw_input("Due Date")


assignment_data = Assignment(assignment_name,due_date)
```

An attempt to move the data into a dictonary in another .py file.

```
f = open(assignments.py)
f.write(str(assignment_data))
f.close()

print assignment_data

print "ok"

f = open(assignments.py)

assignment_data = eval(f.read())

f.close()
```

Comment: You are not storing dictionary ? You are storing `Assignment` objects i guess ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal Storing Assignment objects within a dictonary

Comment: Are there any specific reasons to write the contents to a `.py` file ? you could have used `Pickle` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pickle would also work, for storing data between programs, or even between different runs of the same program::
from module 1:

```
import pickle
f = open(file_Name,'wb')
pickle.dump(assignment_data, f)
f.close()
```

from module 2:

`import pickle
 f = open(file_Name,'rb')
 pickle.load(assignment_data, f)
 f.close()`

(more elegantly with 'with ......')

pickle.load knows that it's getting a dictionary, and it needs to use binary mode both ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create dictionary
assignment_data = {"name": "jane", "date": "late"}

# save dictionary
with open("assignments.py", "wt") as f:
    f.write(repr(assignment_data))

# load dictionary
with open("assignments.py", "rt") as f:
    assignment_data = eval(f.read())
    print assignment_data
```